# NextJS useSearchParams Returns Null

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

In NextJS 14.0.3 / React 18.2.0 given a URL like:

```
http://localhost:3000/mypage?a=apple&b=banana
```

and code, mypage.tsx:

```
'use client'

import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

export default function MyPage() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const a = searchParams.get('a');
  const b = searchParams.get('b');
  console.log("a: ", a);
  console.log("b: ", b);

  return (
    <div></div>
  )
}
```

The console output is:

```
a:  null
b:  null
```

Comment: Can you recreate here : https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/stupefied-germain-mvzspz?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A2%2C1

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it works with these dependencies. maybe it is a bug in your current version

[image]